# React state updates without me calling setState?

Tags: reactjs

Im making a To Do list application with React. My state has items and also deleted items so that they can be restored:

```
  state = {
    items: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'],
    deletedItems: ['item 4', 'item 5']
  };
```

My function to remove items therefore must remove the item from items state and put it into deletedItems state.

```
 removeItem(number) {
    const itemsState = this.state.items;
    const deletedItemsState = this.state.deletedItems;

    const itemToBeDeleted = itemsState[number];
    deletedItemsState.push(itemToBeDeleted);

    itemsState.splice(number, 1);
    this.setState({ items: itemsState });
  }
```

The code above works but I'm confused as to why the deletedItems state is updated without me calling setState on it. Am I not following best practices here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I not following best practices here?

Nope. The problem is that you are not working with temporary variables, like you might believe, but are mutating `deletedItems` directly. Basically:

```
const itemsState = this.state.items;
const deletedItemsState = this.state.deletedItems;
```

These lines do not create a copy of the respective state variables, but instead only creates a reference to them.

So when you do

```
deletedItemsState.push(itemToBeDeleted);
```

you are mutating the state directly! Which is a no-no, as you probably already know.

#### Why does this happen?

To understand this, you must understand that assignments between Primitive and Compound values work differently.

For example:

```
var x = y;
```

`x` will copy the value of `y` if `y` is a string, number, boolean, null or undefined. However, if it's an object, array or a function `x` will store its reference.

---

#### Solution:

What you need to do is to create a shallow copy of them. Like so:

```
const itemsState = this.state.items.slice();
const deletedItemsState = this.state.deletedItems.slice();
```

This will make `itemsState` and `deletedItemsState` separate variables from `this.state.item` and `this.state.deletedItems` respectively.

---

#### Demo:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'],
      deletedItems: ['item 4', 'item 5']
    };
  }

  removeItem = (number) => {
    const itemsState = this.state.items;
    const deletedItemsState = this.state.deletedItems;

    const itemToBeDeleted = itemsState[number];
    deletedItemsState.push(itemToBeDeleted);

    itemsState.splice(number, 1);
    this.setState({
      items: itemsState
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Items:
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map((item, i) => <li>{item} <button onClick={this.removeItem.bind(this, i)}>Remove</button></li>)}
        </ul>
        Deleted Items:
         <ul>
          {this.state.deletedItems.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < MyApp / > , document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to handle state changes in your app.

For instance, this line

```
const itemsState = this.state.items;
```

It creates a variable itemsState which points to this.state.items. So any changes you make to itemsState, it will get changed in your state.items as well. This mutates your data.

The best practice is to use a library such as [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) to make state updates or either clone your state object into variables and then perform mutations on them. And after you are done, finally update the state using setState().

Here is a code snippet to explain how you can clone using *Object.assign()*. This won't change your original state variables as you can see in the snippet.

```js
var state = {
    items: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'],
    deletedItems: ['item 4', 'item 5']
  };
  
function removeItem(number) {
    const itemsState = Object.assign([], this.state.items);
    const deletedItemsState = Object.assign([], this.state.deletedItems);

    const itemToBeDeleted = itemsState[number];
    deletedItemsState.push(itemToBeDeleted);

    itemsState.splice(number, 1);
    //this.setState({ items: itemsState });
    
    console.log(state);
  }
  
removeItem(1);
```